# Как подобрать мотор на робота.

Tags: проектирование

Не уверен, отвечают ли здесь на такие вопросы, но всё же(поправьте, если что).
Собираюсь сделать из своего домашнего пылесоса робота-уборщика, с уже придуманным мной алгоритмом. Плату уже подобрал (Arduino), да и многие детали уже продумал. Но не могу понять, какой силы мне покупать мотор и, соответственно, какой мощности брать аккумулятор(может вообще от сети всё будет). 
Есть ли какой-то алгоритм для подборки мощности мотора? Может нужно динамометром потаскать пылесос?

Пылесос весит 5 кг + всякие платы и свистелки 2 кг. При том всего 2 колеса, а часть веса перераспределяется на пол (нашёл алгоритм только для 4-х колёс 
http://www.robotics.ru/volov/Rover1_rus.html). Собираюсь передавать вращение либо напрямую в колёса пылесоса, либо через контакт маленьких колёс, подсоединённых к мотору, и колёс пылесоса (они в диаметре 40 см). 
Как подобрать нужный? И, если можно, дайте ссылку на примеры подобных моторов.

Comment: зачем уборщика? лучше отдай ему кожаную куртку и мотоцикл..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот взял тот же заголовок, что и в статье по ссылке http://www.robotics.ru/volov/Rover1_rus.html, поменял «четырьмя» на «двумя» и спросил у Гугола. Угадайте, что нашел :)

[Мобильный робот с двумя приводными колесами и одним опорным](http://www.robotics.ru/volov/Homeroboter1_rus.html)